# exec-maven-plugin doesn't work on windows

Tags: maven

What I am trying is to get the project version, project artifact-Id etc. from pom.xml.

I have started with just to print hello string through command line,

mvn --non-recursive org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:exec -Dexec.executable=CMD -Dexec.args='/C' -Dexec.args='ECHO' -Dexec.args='hello'

Somehow its not printing the string, any help is much appreciated.

[image]

My understanding was, below command should echo the project version but its not.

mvn --non-recursive org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:exec -Dexec.executable=CMD -Dexec.args='/C' -Dexec.args='ECHO' -Dexec.args='${project.version}'

Comment: Please do not use screenshots for console output. You can simple mark and copy the console text and paste it into your question.

Comment: @Robert noted, thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a better solution.

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:3.1.0:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version
```

That will print out the information with scattered other information. This can be improved by using the following:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:3.1.0:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout
```

If you have correctly define the version of the maven-help-plugin in your pom file this can be simplified like this:

```
mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout
```

By using this you can access any kind of information within the pom file like `artfaictId`, `groupId` etc.

```
mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.groupId -q -DforceStdout
```

I recommend to use the most recent version of Maven (3.5.4)..

Comment: Thanks @khmarbaise, why this cant be achived using exec-maven-plugin. We have been using it for Linux environment. However, when I try this plugin for windows using powershell command it didn't work. Any idea ?

Comment: The exec-maven-plugin will execute on the operation system with it's parameters it depends on the running operation system...that's the reason...The solution I gave is independent of the operation system.....

Comment: Hi @khmarbaise, I observed one problem with this when outputting the information using '-q -DforceStdout', if the information did not find in pom.xml it gives "null object or invalid expression", I was expecting empty or just say null. This is weird. any clue ?